# How to extract a .rar archive with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to unpack an .rar archive with Ruby. I could not find a gem though.
I discovered the [rar](https://github.com/mkroman/rar) gem which only allows to create an archive. How can I extract a rar file, not just create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some additional reading on the subject it seems that any gems that were for this are basically abandoned. But, you can `brew install unrar` and use that from Ruby `system('unrar l your_file.rar')`.

Comment: I would prefer a gem if possible. I tried `gem 'rar_file', git: 'git@github.com:johanlunds/rar_file.git'` without success.

Answer (score 4):

[ffi-libarchive](https://github.com/chef/ffi-libarchive) provides a gem-based solution. It works for rar files even though they don't specifically mention it (see [issue #151](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/151)). Add this to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'ffi-libarchive'
```

and then execute:

```
$ bundle
```